# How to increment an value inside an array of objects in MongoDB with mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

Let's say my model looks like this:

```
 const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  award: [
    one: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    two: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    three: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    four: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  ]
)}
```

And I a controller that when called by the post ID, it increments the number of the award (For example "two") that comes in the body.

```
exports.awardPost = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const post= await Post.findById({id: req.params.cardid},
  if(!post){
    res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      message: 'Card not found'
    })
  }
  post.update("Increment by one req.body.awardname"); <- What is the best way to do that here ? 
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    card
  })
});
```

I've been struggling with that for a while, what is the correct way to do it in such situations ?

Comment: Is `CardSchema` is in an array of another schema ? Please edit this question with actual sample docs & required o/p..

Comment: Ups my bad, I had the wrong schema name. No, it's not an array of another schema

Comment: Then what does your title mean ? *inside an array of Objects* ? Did you try `$inc` operator ?